# Selectize with flag image - border CSS fix

Tags: css, selectize.js

I used below script & CSS to make select working as expected using selectize plugin. All ok in functionality.

http://codepen.io/venkatTDG/pen/LxmwPL

**JS:**

```
var COUNTRIES=[
{ code:"ch", name:"中文"},
     { code:"jp", name:"Japan"},
     { code:"kr", name:"Korea"},
     { code:"vn", name:"Vietnam"},
     { code:"uk", name:"United Kingdom"}
];


$('#country-selectize').selectize({
maxItems: 1,
labelField: 'name',
valueField: 'code',
plugins: ['remove_button'],
searchField: ['name', 'code'],
options: COUNTRIES,
preload: true,
persist: false,
render: {
    item: function(item, escape) {
        return "<div><img src='' class='flag flag-" + escape(item.code) + "' alt='flag' />&nbsp;" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
    },
    option: function(item, escape) {
        return "<div><img src='' class='flag flag-" + escape(item.code) + "' alt='flag' />&nbsp;" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
    }
},
});
```

I need CSS help. Not sure why I am getting 1px border color around image. I tried in different way to remove, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using an image tag with source="", this is causing a bordered outline with alternative text for image i.e `flag`

So use a span instead of image tag

```
item: function(item, escape) {
    return "<div><span class='flag flag-" + escape(item.code) + "' />&nbsp;" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
},
option: function(item, escape) {
    return "<div><span class='flag flag-" + escape(item.code) + "' />&nbsp;" + escape(item.name) + "</div>";
}
```

[Updadated code](http://codepen.io/sujanadiga/pen/rjvXpj)